# RMI Java server and client will not communicate

Tags: java, rmi

RMIclient,
THIS IS THE CLIENT

```
package rmiclient;

import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.*;

public class RMIClient {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    RMIClient client = new RMIClient();
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    if(args.length == 0)
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter the correct server, exiting.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    client.runMenu(args);
}//end Main()

public void runMenu(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        int commandToRun = 0;
        int numberOfThreads;
        Scanner commandScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner threadScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter the number for the command that you wish to execute.");
        System.out.println("1. Date & Time \n"
                + "2. Server Uptime \n"
                + "3. Memory Usage \n"
                + "4. Netstat \n"
                + "5. Current Users \n"
                + "6. Running processes \n"
                + "7. Exit");
        commandToRun = commandScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        if (commandToRun == 7) {
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(commandToRun > 7 || commandToRun < 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid command");
        } 
       /* else {
    if(commandToRun == 1 || commandToRun == 4)
    {
            System.out.println("Enter number of threads to run");
            numberOfThreads = threadScanner.nextInt();
            clientThreads thread[] = new clientThreads[numberOfThreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                thread[i] = new clientThreads(args, commandToRun);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                thread[i].start();
        try{
        thread[i].join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    }
    else{
    numberOfThreads = 1;
            clientThreads thread[] = new clientThreads[numberOfThreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                thread[i] = new clientThreads(args, commandToRun);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                thread[i].start();
        try{
        thread[i].join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}}
            }*/
        } 
    }
}


class clientThreads extends Thread {

int commandToRun;
String host;

public clientThreads(String[] args, int commandToRun) {
    this.commandToRun = commandToRun;
    this.host = args[0];
}

public void run() {
    String serverResponse = "";
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1225);
        RMIInterface stub = (RMIInterface)registry.lookup("runCommand");
        serverResponse = stub.runCommand(commandToRun);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
System.out.println();
    System.out.println(serverResponse);
}
```

}

RMIINTERFACE, Interface

```
package rmiclient;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {
String runCommand(int commandToRun) throws RemoteException;
```

}

RMIserver, this is the server

```
package rmiserver;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
//import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.io.*;


public class RMIServer implements RMIInterface {

public RMIServer() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
        RMIServer obj = new RMIServer();
     //   System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        RMIInterface stub = (RMIInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1225);
        registry.rebind("runCommand", stub);
        System.out.println("Server starting");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String runCommand(int commandToRun) throws RemoteException {
    Runtime runtime = null;
    Process process = null;
    String command = "";
    String output = "";
    String newLine = "";
    BufferedReader inp = null;

    try {
        if (commandToRun == 1) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Date and Time");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "date";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            output = inp.readLine();
        } else if (commandToRun == 2) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Uptime");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "uptime";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            output = inp.readLine();
        } else if (commandToRun == 3) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Memory Use");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "free";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((newLine = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                output = output + "\n" + newLine;
            }
        } else if (commandToRun == 4) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Netstat");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "netstat";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((newLine = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                output = output + "\n" + newLine;
            }
        } else if (commandToRun == 5) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Current Users");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "who";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((newLine = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                output = output + "\n" + newLine;
            }
        } else if (commandToRun == 6) {
            System.out.println("Running command: Running Processes");
            runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            command = "ps -e";
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((newLine = inp.readLine()) != null) {
                output = output + "\n" + newLine;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return output;
}
```

}

Please help, i feel like i'm pretty close to getting the client and server. were pretty close to getting them connected utilizing the SSH secure shell. 
after the client and server start communicating  it should be easy to finish this program, when finished it will be able to take input from client (a number 1-10) and based off that number give the response from the server.

Comment: You could probably stand to be a little more specific than "it doesn't work."

Comment: both programs run in SSH but having difficulty getting the client to communicate with the server process. ive tried hardcoding the port numbers but that stilll does not work.

Comment: 'Having difficulty' is just as vague as 'doesn't work'. Try harder.